# PHP curl is not working on Windows and Apache

Tags: php, windows, curl

PHP Curl is not working on Windows and APACHE. I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\Apache24...

What should I do?

Curl is installed but it is not showing up in phpinfo.

Answer (score 1):

Enable extension `php_curl`in php.ini

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

This solution is proposed based on Wamp. In other systems it may very. See @Mike's comment below this answer.

Comment: It depends on your system's setup. For Debian-based distros, the standard is to create a symbolic link in the /etc/php5/{type}/conf.d/ to /etc/php5/mods-available/ instead of hard-coding it like that into your php.ini. I would assume other distros would be similar. Also, if a file exists in the mods-available directory, you know it's actually installed and available (unless you've been messing with it manually somehow).

Answer (score 0):

For `windows 7` Some users have faced similar problem with `easyphp`. It has a solution for easyphp that I used once.

1) Installing/copying the bundle into `D:/` drive instead of `C:/` (assuming here it has windows).

2) Save a copy of your `php.ini` file at `C:/Windows` folder as well. Also, you can check which ini file is loaded by your php from the `phpinfo()`.

Now restart your apache, and it may work for you too.

Comment: Yes. You'll see the curl extension there along with other things like mysql, openssl, etc. Just do a ctrl+f and search for curl on the page. If nothing, then extension is not enabled yet.

Answer (score 0):

Had the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50365941/php-curl-suddenly-not-loading-on-windows-10-pro) recently on my Windows 10 Pro notebook. Fixed it by just installing the latest Apache for Windows.