# PHP cURL suddenly not loading on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

A simple [php_curl example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) isn't working anymore on my Windows 10 laptop. It was working before.

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\Users\path\curl.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\path\curl.php on line 3`

My C:\php7\php.ini has extension=C:\php7\ext\php_curl.dll
php_curl.dll exists in C:\php7\ext

PHP Version 7.0.30
Windows 10 Pro Version 1607 Build 14393.2189

But my loclahost/phpinfo.php does not have cURL. How come all of a sudden it disappeared ?

PS : The script worked in the command line. It's just that Apache is not loading the extension.

Comment: Where is your Apache installed. Look in the `bin` folder in there and you will probably find another `php.ini` file. That is what PHP uses when running under Apache

Comment: To be absolutely sure where PHP is getting its config from, LOOK at the output from `phpinfo()` at the item labeled `Loaded Configuration File`

Comment: The `php.ini` file in the `C:\php7` is normally used only for configuring the PHP CLI

Comment: Loaded Configuration File : C:\php7\php.ini

Comment: This is what I had added in my httpd.conf file :

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
LoadModule php7_module "c:/php7/php7apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "c:/php7"`

Comment: Then did you check the PHP Error log?

Comment: And does other PHP code actually run ok?

Comment: Put php.ini in the Apache root folder, one level up from bin. You can also debug the config with a simple script like `<? phpinfo() ?>`

Answer (score 1):

don't know why it `suddenly stopped working`, but first run `<?php phpinfo(~0);` , and check which php.ini file that is actually loaded (this avoids editing the wrong php.ini file to no avail) [image: https://i.imgur.com/KBgZxYv.png] (in this example, it is `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini`), then edit that php.ini file, if that file actually has the `extension=C:\php7\ext\php_curl.dll` line, then some combination of the following settings are set wrong:

`display_startup_errors` is `Off`, change it to `On`

`display_errors` is `Off`, change it to `On`

`error_reporting` is not `E_ALL`, change it to `error_reporting=E_ALL` (and nothing else, not like `error_reporting= E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` or whatever, just E_ALL)

`html_errors` is `Off`, change it to `On`

then restart apache, again check the phpinfo() page, and verify that the new configuration options are actually loaded, then run `<?php curl_init();`, and it should show an error about why the curl extension could not be loaded.

Comment: Checked all of your statuses. Loaded Configuration File  is C:\php7\php.ini . All the settings are On, On, E_ALL an On. \Users\anjan>C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe starts without any errors.

Comment: @anjanesh and what happens when you load a page containing `<?php echo "start."; $ch=curl_init(); var_dump($ch); echo "end.";?>`  ?

Comment: start.
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\Users\path\test\curl.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\path\test\curl.php on line 3

Comment: @anjanesh hmm, error_log is empty, so any errors are sent to apache's error log. what does the `ErrorLog` directive of apache's `httpd.conf` say? (on xampp, it's `ErrorLog "logs/error.log"` by default)

Comment: ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

[Fri May 18 18:43:42.211169 2018] [:error] [pid 10844:tid 1160] [client ::1:52046] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\\Users\\anjan\\Dropbox\\vhosts\\planbuildr\\test\\curl.php:3\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in C:\\Users\\anjan\\Dropbox\\vhosts\\planbuildr\\test\\curl.php on line 3

Comment: @anjanesh `type C:\php7\php.ini | pastebinit`

Answer (score 1):

I came across some links on other StackOverflow answers (will post the links here if I trace them again). I had Apache 2.4.23 Win64 - I reinstalled Apache to the latest one - 2.4.33 Win64 - and now cURL is working.